# Typescript ternary operator breaks identity type

Tags: typescript, conditional-operator

Why is my `SupposedId` type below not a type identity?

Typescript is complaining that `Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'SupposedId<T>'`.

How comes `T` cannot be assignable to either `T` or `T`, what am I missing?

```
type SupposedId<T> = T extends object ? T : T;

function makeId<T>(test: T): SupposedId<T> {
  return test // <- Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'SupposedId<T>'
}
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygrmMB7AzhAJgSXQHgCoB8UAvFHlBAB7AQB26KUSARgFYQDGwUA-GVAC4yAbgBQogGZxaXAJZJaUALYBDANYRs+AgAoaKYELwBKIfESoMWwlADeoqFABOEYHCeL93APTeoOAFoycGgAcjxQqFlGWiRuFRQUWQBzWhVmABtoYCQoUEgoUPNkNCxcQlDRAF8gA)

Comment: That's interesting. But what's the point of `SupposedId`? I'm not asking to dismiss the issue (which is definitely interesting), but it may help us understand your end goal.

Comment: The type definition for `SupposedId<T>` is not correctly defining a type identity.

It is saying that if `T` extends object, then `SupposedId<T>` is equal to `T`, otherwise it's equal to `T`.
Since all types extend object, `T` will always be assignable to `T`, but not to `SupposedId<T>`.

You should change your definition to: `type SupposedId<T> = T;`

This way, `SupposedId<T>` will be the exact same type as `T` and the function makeId will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks all, @T.J.Crowder I want to work on one of the branches of the condition, and I just boiled the issue down to this.

Comment: @baggiogiacomo Not all types extend `object` - primitives such as string, number, and bool are not objects.

Comment: @baggiogiacomo - [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFhAxgawDwBUB8UC8V1QQAewEAdgCYDOUA9gEYBWSwUA-FMAE4Cu0AXFABmAQwA2VCAG4AUDNCQoAQVywEKVA2aJgmWQHp9UYwD02chdABCq+EjRVuASzIBzPTMPGoZi+GgwtupoZDwAtvQQXB5epuZAA)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of [distributed conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types). SupposedId distributes to `T extends any | T extends object`. Yours is certainly a novel case, since they both actually resolve to `T`, but the conditional type performs different narrowing based on whether or not `T extends object`.

However, per the documentation, you can fix it by adding square brackets around each side of the extends keyword:

```js
type SupposedId<T> = [T] extends [object] ? T : T;

function makeId<T>(test: T): SupposedId<T> {
  /* `test` is now one of `T extends object` or `T extends any`,
     not `T extends object | T extends any` */
  return test;
}
```